# Spark date_format and weekInYear/date - number starting on Monday instead of Sunday

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to get the week of year using

```
weekofyear(date) and
date_format(date, 'ww')
```

but the increment for a week number is on SUNDAY.

How can I make the week start on MONDAY instead?

I prefer the date_format as it prepends a 0 when needed, but anything will do!

Thanks

Comment: what's `weekInYear` ? you can use `weekofyear()`  where a week is considered to start on a Monday.

Comment: Sorry I meant weekofyear() yes duh - no this starts on a Sunday